# Print a web view content with a static header

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, webview, pdf-generation

> Note: I am working with with Swift 4 for macOS.

I have an `NSTableView` which can be filled with data and saved into Core Data.
I would like to display the TableView values with a "design".

I have realized it like this:

- created a html template
- get the html code as a string and replaces the "html placeholders" with my tableview values
- show the modified html string via Web View

[image]

**Works good ! And this "solution" will do automatically page breaks :)**

Here a little bit of my code

```
// Example with statics values
func createHTML() {
        let pathToHTMLTemplate = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("basic.html")
        let pathToNoticeHTMLTemplate = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("notice.html")
        do {
            htmlString = try String(contentsOf: pathToInvoiceHTMLTemplate)
            for _ in 0 ..< 40 {
                var itemHTMLContent = try String(contentsOf: pathToNoticeHTMLTemplate)
                itemHTMLContent = itemHTMLContent.replacingOccurrences(of: "#NOTICE_NAME#", with: "My notice")
                htmlPositionen += itemHTMLContent
            }
            htmlString = htmlString.replacingOccurrences(of: "#NOTICE#", with: htmlPositionen)
            let totalCount = 20 //Fix value as example
            htmlString = htmlString.replacingOccurrences(of: "#TOTAL_COUNT#", with: "\(totalCount)")
            myWebView.mainFrame.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
        } catch {}
    }
```

And I can print this:

```
func webView(_ sender: WebView!, didFinishLoadFor frame: WebFrame!) {

        let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("test.pdf")

        let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.shared
        printInfo.paperSize = NSMakeSize(595.22, 841.85)
        printInfo.isHorizontallyCentered = true
        printInfo.isVerticallyCentered = true
        printInfo.orientation = .portrait
        printInfo.topMargin = 50
        printInfo.rightMargin = 0
        printInfo.bottomMargin = 50
        printInfo.leftMargin = 0
        printInfo.verticalPagination = .autoPagination

        let printOp = NSPrintOperation(view: sender.mainFrame.frameView.documentView, printInfo: printInfo)

        printOp.showsProgressPanel = false
        printOp.showsPrintPanel = false
        printOp.run()
        printOp.cleanUp()
    }
```

But there is a problem:
 - I would like to have the red "Notice-header" after each page break again on the top

Have anybody an idea, how I can realize that?

**UPDATE**

Maybe this methods of web view could helps?

```
func webView(_ sender: WebView!, drawFooterIn rect: NSRect) {
   // DO SOMETHING
}

func webView(_ sender: WebView!, drawHeaderIn rect: NSRect) {
   // DO SOMETHING
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you're not specifying to use a header for the pages, but you're just displaying the notice once.

You might want to set the `nsprintinfo.headerandfooter` attribute to define that a header should be printed, and then move the header text/display text (NOTICE etc.) into that section.

Not sure if the `NSView` will be beneficial for you here... there's a good section on printing here: [Printing Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_printingapi/osxp_printingapi.html)